# Planet Express Ship Blueprints

Tags: futurama

Is there a blueprint for the Planet Express Ship?  We've seen most of the ship but it's not defined where all the rooms are.  Currently we've seen the deck, loading dock, the hallway, the kitchen, the living quarters, and the captain's quarters.  How does this fit inside the Planet Express Ship?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I don't know if there is any canon layout of the ship, but I've found [an old archived site](http://web.archive.org/web/20071112090617/http://www.geocities.com/payndz2/planetblueprints.html) that conjectures what the design would have to be to accommodate nearly [all of the currently known rooms](http://theinfosphere.org/Planet_Express_ship#Parts_of_the_ship). Here are the suggested blueprints from that site:

**Side view:**

[image]

**Deck 1:**

[image]

**Deck 2:**

[image]

**Deck 3:**

[image]